# javascript error in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My code is producing this error:

```
`ReferenceError: "cell" is not defined. (Line 7, file "Code")`
```

I would like to be notified when any cells in the "AR" column were edited.
[image: picture of spreadsheet]

My code:

```
function onEdit() { //To get email notification if any changes to the particular cells 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Notificações"); 
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation(); 
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "fabiano.ars95@outlook.com";
  var message = ''; 
  if( cell.indexOf('AQ') != -1 ) {// means that if you edit column AQ 
    var subject ='Notificação de Alta Prioridade ';
    var body =' Você acaba de receber uma notificação de alta prioridade. Acesse sua planilha de notificações para que possa elaborar uma tratativa' Logger.log(body);
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients,subject,body); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: the Code that i'm using: function onEdit(){
  //To get email notification if any changes to the perticular cells
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Notificações");
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "fabiano.ars95@outlook.com";

Comment: var message = ''; 
if(cell.indexOf('AQ')!=-1) {// means that if you edit column AQ
    var subject ='Notificação de Alta Prioridade '
    var body =' Você acaba de receber uma notificação de alta prioridade. Acesse sua planilha de notificações para que possa elaborar uma tratativa' 
    Logger.log(body); 
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients,subject,body);
  }
}

Comment: I've already change 'AQ' for 'AR' but still appear: 
ReferenceError: "cell" is not defined. (Line 7, file "Code") Dismissal

Comment: Please read this and try again:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Some things to pay attention to in particular:  post the code, not a picture; post it in the question, not in comments; make it an [mcve].  jsfiddle.net may be relevant.  Make it easy for us to run your code and see the problem and you'll get more, better, and quicker responses.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code to one of my sheets.
The only Error message I had was

> Missing ; before statement. (line 10, file "Copy of Code").

After changing *Prioridade ' var* into Prioridade **;** ' var and adding another semicolon in between *tratativa' Logger*, I succesfully get an email notification upon changes.

Complete code:

```
function onEdit() { //To get email notification if any changes to the perticular cells`
    var ss          = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet       = ss.getSheetByName("Notificações");
    var cell        = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
    var cellvalue   = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString() ;
    var recipients  = "fabiano.ars95@outlook.com"
    var message     = ''; 

    if(cell.indexOf('AR')!=-1) {// means that if you edit column AQ
        var subject  ='Notificação de Alta Prioridade ' ;
        var body     =' Você acaba de receber uma notificação de alta prioridade. Acesse sua planilha de notificações para que possa elaborar uma tratativa'; Logger.log(body);
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients,subject,body); 
    } 
}
```